# Advanced search: Date range with zero value deactivates filter

Tags: feature-request, search

- `created:2d..1d` gives results from day before yesterday to yesterday
- `created:1d..` gives results from yesterday to now
- `created:1d..0d` gives **all** results. I expect it to return the same results as `created:1d..`

Confuses me every time. Note this is even more confusing when used in a larger query, such as combining `createdat` and `lastactive` in combination, where the erroneous results are sporadic.

Would be nice if zero values could be treated as now.

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: This seems like more of a bug to me

Comment: What is the expect result from `created:1d..0d`?

Comment: Same as "1d.." Date range from one day ago to now.

Comment: If you can use `1d..` to create the search to replicate what you expect `1d..0d` to do, then I'm not sure there is any issue here. This definitely isn't a feature request, it's a bug at best, which I don't think needs fixing unless I'm missing something?!

Comment: @Tanner: For me this is a usability issue. I keep using the unsupported form '..0d' getting weird results. Whether this is a bug or feature request depends on whether the documentation must be understood to allow '..0d' or not. Like most usability issues, this does not "need fixing", unless you care about usability. I guess at some point I will learn to remember, and so will anyone else running into this.

Comment: That sounds more like a work-around than a fix.

Comment: You haven't seen [`find ... -mtime`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days/200050#200050) yet.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I didn't remember that one..